# dynamically filter handlebars template based upon checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I'm working on my first handlebars.project, and I'm currently trying to figure out how to refresh my template without reloading the page.

My template is pulling data from a JSON file, and based upon different checkbox values I want to dynamically change which templates are being displayed.

Would using partial templates be the best approach for this?

If that's not a solution I was thinking about filtering my JSON on every checkbox change and passing the new JSON to handlebars to recompile without reloading the page.

Thanks in advance for the help!

example code.  trying to refresh template based upon which property of JSON objects is selected in the checkbox:

```
<script id="test" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
        <li>
            <ul class="list-description">
                    <li><span>Type of Device: </span>{{type}}</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

For the sake of this example lets say {{type}} can be either smartphone, tablet, laptop, desktop.

Comment: My current approach is filtering my data before sending it to handlebars.  I just need to figure out how to refresh my handlebars template without a page refresh.

Comment: The solution I ended up using was creating a function that calls .hide on every div column on load.  After this I simply call show when I want that column to be revealed.